# Why is my program to read a vector of strings into an array of character pointers not displaying any output?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

I'm on exercise 4.34 of the book C++ Primer, 4th edition, which states "Write a program to read strings into a vector. Now, copy that vector into an array of character pointers. For each element in the vector, allocate a new character array and copy the data from the vector element into that character array. Then insert a pointer to the character array into the array of character pointers." I'm also trying to print the vector and character pointer array, and delete the character pointer array afterwards.
Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter some strings:" << endl;
    
    vector<string> svec;
    string input;
    
    while (cin >> input) {
        svec.push_back(input);
    }
    
    size_t sarr_sz = svec.size();
    char **sarr = new char*[sarr_sz];
    
    size_t carr_sz, carr_num;
    char *carr = NULL;
    
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < svec.size(); ++i) {
        carr_num = i;
        carr_sz = svec[i].size();
        carr = new char[carr_sz + 1];
        
        size_t cval;
        
        for (string::size_type j = 0; j < svec[i].size(); ++j) {
            cval = j;
            carr[cval] = svec[i][j];
        }
        
        cval = svec[i].size();
        carr[cval] = '\0';
        
        sarr[carr_num] = carr;
    }
    
    cout << "Vector contents:" << endl;
    
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < svec.size(); ++i) {
        cout << svec[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Character pointer array contents:" << endl;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sarr_sz; ++i) {
        cout << sarr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sarr_sz; ++i) {
        delete [] sarr[i];
    }
    
    delete [] sarr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this program, it freezes at the point after entering the string input and displays no output. When I exit the program manually using `Ctrl-C`, it displays either `Vector Output: <first string inputted>` or just `Vector Output:`. I've gone over the program multiple times and can't figure out where I've made an error.
Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner, and I'm just following the conventions of the book. As such, my program is probably neither efficient nor follows correct style. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you pressing `ctrl+d` on Linux/Mac or `ctrl+z` on Windows to generate an `EOF` to exit the loop? If not then your program is just waiting for more input since an error on the stream is the only way that loop will exit. Works fine for me here: https://godbolt.org/z/MaWcdxrKz

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so dumb. I'm used to programming on a Bash shell and only recently switched to Powershell on Windows. I've been using `Ctrl-D` to generate `EOF`. That's why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: I have the opposite problem sometimes. I press ctrl-z on the Mac and wonder what happened for a minute.